# Str_to_date in Load File leads to NULL value

Tags: mysql, database, csv

The field in the table I am targeting is
date_sent DATE

And here is a portion of the CSV and the following import query. Why is the date field being set to NULL?

```
1,"1/21/2013","0",1
2,"2/27/2013","0",1
```

This is the SQL

```
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Me/CSV.csv'
     INTO TABLE Collections
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(`id`, @DATE_STR, `col`, `sid`)
SET `date_sent` = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE_STR, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL's dev pages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
%m        Month, numeric (00..12)
%d        Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
```

You need to use `%c` instead(probably `%e` too).

```
%c        Month, numeric (0..12)
%e        Day of the month, numeric (0..31)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this date format:

```
STR_TO_DATE(@DATE_STR, '%c/%e/%Y')
```

- `%c` is the month, numeric, `0..12` while `%m` is the month in the format `00..12`
- `%e` is the day of the month, numeric, `0..31` while `%d` is the day in the format `00..31`

Please see the documentation of [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).